# Even though I installed ffmpeg , I got "ERROR:spleeter:ffmpeg binary not found"

Tags: ffmpeg, spleeter

Even though I installed ffmpeg ,   I got error saying "ERROR:spleeter:ffmpeg binary not found"

how can I solve this problem

I installed ffmpeg using "pip install ffmpeg"

Comment: `ffmpeg-python` is a package which runs ffmpeg program. So you need to install the program in order to use it. Go to https://ffmpeg.org

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip uninstall ffmpeg
```

And then:

```
pip install ffmpeg-python
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Same error every time.

Comment: You need to add the binary to path.